# Qt with Windows 10 transparent widget not working

Tags: python, qt

I am working on put some drawings over some child widgets in a window. So I came up with a transparent overlay widget, making its background transparent, putting it on top of the other windows, painting directly on it. It all worked fine on Mac. However, this overlay widget just won't show up in Windows 10. Here are some code for creating this overlay transparent widget:

```
class OverlayWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super(OverlayWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags( Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Widget | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.TransparentMode)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.org_x = x
        self.org_y = y
        self.window_width = width
        self.window_height = height

        self.setGeometry(self.org_x, self.org_y, self.window_width, self.window_height)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setCursor(Qt.BlankCursor)
```

Once I set the WA_TranslucentBackground attribute, nothing shows up, even the mouse cursor won't change, which means this widget probably wasn't even loaded. Any suggestions?

EDIT: 
It seems that this is related to how this widget is added to its parent. If I create a layout and add it to the layout and then set its parent layout as the one I just created, it did show up. However, doing this contradicts with my purpose of overlaying it on top of another existing layout.

But if I just created this widget by passing the parent widget into it constructor, it doesn't work in Windows, but works in Mac.

This is quite annoying.

Comment: What is EQt? Typo?

Comment: That's typo. Fixed. Thanks for spotting it. @StefanMonov

Comment: @BillQ did you ever find a solution? I'm having similar problems.